# How can I get font size for UILabel in custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I have UITableView with cells that have custom classes, eg `HistoryCell`

Cell UI elements are composed in interface builder and linked with class properties:

```
@IBOutlet var contentLabel: UILabel!
```

My task is set properly height for such cells because of `contentLabel` is multiline. I want to calculate height using `String.boundingRect` method, but it required `UIFont`

I can just copy font properties from interface builder to code in develop-time, but if font will be changed in future, code will be needed to fix

Instead that I want to get font from in-memory cell
I creates static instance and use it for return font:

```
class HistoryCell: UITableViewCell {
    private static let instance = HistoryCell()

    static func textFont() -> UIFont {
        return instance.contentLabel.font
    }
}
```

But when I calls `HistoryCell.textFont` method, `contentLabel` is `nil`

Why it's nil?
Can I get cell element font some another way?

Comment: Did you check connect IBOutlet to contentLable?

Comment: You have to be sure to check it after the view was "loaded". For example try it in `awakeFromNib()`

Comment: @Tobonaut, is it possible when tableview cells are in storyboard not in own xib files?

Comment: Yes. This is an old time fella. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have connected **contentLabel** using **IBOutlet** and when you create a instance of HistoryCell, it doesn't load nib file references. Because of this **it return you nil object for contentLabel**

You can do same with

```
open func textFont() -> UIFont {
   return self.titlelabel.font
}
```

and call this function using object of cell which is received using dequeue func

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ParallexCell", for: indexPath) as! HistoryCell
let font = cell.textFont()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution without font calculating:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt
    indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```